# tsql join only if exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

i have this piece of code in mssql:

```
SELECT [dbo].[ManagerUser].*,
       [names].[ManagerUserNames].[namesStyle]
        FROM [dbo].[ManagerUser]
    INNER JOIN [names].[ManagerUserNames]
    ON [names].[ManagerUserNames].[ManagerUserId] = (SELECT top 1 [Id] 
                                                    FROM [dbo].[ManagerUser] 
                                                    WHERE [Email]=@Email)
 AND GETUTCDATE() > [StartDate] AND (Getutcdate() < [EndDate] OR [EndDate] IS NULL)
WHERE [Email]=@Email AND [names].[ManagerUserNames].[Status] = 1
```

what i want is to fetch all data from `[dbo].[ManagerUser]` where `WHERE [Email]=@Email`
but also get the `NamesStyle` from `[names].[ManagerUserNames]` ONLY IF IT EXISTS.

problem is I dont get the user if he doesn't have a name style status.

i want to get the `namesStyle` only if exists for the user by `email`.

***EDIT***
There might be no NameStyle, consider that. that is the issue

Thanks

Comment: if there's no `namesStyle`, what do you want the default to be?

Comment: i dont mind, some string "NA" is good for instance

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `inner join` with a `LEFT join`? and wrapping the `namesStyle` with `ISNULL`?

Comment: @christiandev somebody posted this answer, it didnt work for me.. he deleted the answer

Comment: The more i read your explanations and compare them to your SQL statement, the less i understand the goal of your SQL. Could you please show your current (errorneous) output and show the one expected? I think, the ON expression inside the JOIN is weird, but I need more information.

Comment: i hope you realize by now that those are not the names im using, i didnt want to expose those parameters because system is on production.
the ON expression is wierd because i need to get the NamesStyle out of  ManagerUserNames where the same user id is at.